# 2012 HYUNDAI ELANTRA KEY FOB

Tags: remote-start

Not sure if I am asking the right question, But I haven't even had my car a full year and I am possibly having issues with my keyless remote fob I believe. When I click to lock or unlock it doesn't respond, nor does it start my car.
with that being said, 1. does this mean i need to change the battery?
2. if i change the battery will this help my car to start, or will it have to be reprogrammed?

Answer (score 1):

I have no experience with your model Hyundai.

However, the first thing to try with a non-working (or now-and-then non-working) remote is to remove its battery, buy a new battery of the correct type, clean both the battery contacts in the remote as well as the battery faces, then install the new battery in the remote. That should restore the remote to operability, i.e., it'll transmit when its buttons are pushed. Changing only the remote battery may not require re-pairing the remote with the car.

Comment: Many fobs **need** re-pairing after removing their battery or batteries... My car definitely does...

Comment: @SolarMike Certainly, that's why I said "many." I've had this issue on VWs and Hondas, and found re-pairing unnecessary. In any event, making sure the remote's battery is good and its connections clean is still the proper first step.

Comment: can’t see « many » in your answer... I do see « unlikely » which is what I did not agree with ... I, from experience, find it necessary to re-pair the keys and that tends to mean **all** keys associated to that car...

Comment: @SolarMike I changed "unlikely" to "may not."

Comment: Davids answer is good advice however the comments I do not agree with. it is extremely rare that a remote would lose its programming because of changing the battery. Most all remotes ID values are fixed in it's firmware. It's like saying your computer will lose its programming if you leave it unplugged too long. It is actually more common for your car to lose its memory of the remotes ID from changing the car's battery but even this is not typical because the remotes are stored in eeprom memories which are designed to not require power to retain the data.

Answer (score 1):

The lock and unlock functions are impacted by the key fob battery. See this [YOUCANIC guide on how to change the battery on your keyfob](https://www.youcanic.com/vehicle/hyundai/replace-key-fob-battery). It is very easy.

As far as starting the engine, it should not be impacted by the key fob battery. The key has a transponder inside that is recognized by the car. The ignition induces an electric field on the key when you insert it to read the code on the key. That's why the key should work to start the car even with a dead battery.

Comment: If this is  is a proximity fob, battery does control the proximity feature to start the car.  if the battery in the prox is bad then you have to insert the remote into a slot that's located in the center console or the glove box and then the individual transponder coil can be activated which is separate from the proximity function and the keyless entry function. Many people do not know about the slots so I I get these calls all the time where people think it's their keys are failing

Comment: Yes it controls the proximity feature, but if you press the START button with the keyfob it will start even if the key fob battery is dead.

Comment: Your answer was good and I uped it, just wanted to clear up the point you made "As far as starting the engine, it should not be impacted by the key fob battery." Because many people do not know they can use the emergency starting when prox battery is dead. Pressing prox to button on this one will not work. Hyundai's this year Have slots you need to place the prox in. Either in glove box or center console box. Its a little hidden.